# Devise - Confirmação email e Forget password? [ e-mail não envia ]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, email

## Problema no envia de E-mail de confirmação e Alteração de Senha

#### Problema

Após solicitar o envio do `forget password?` ele fica carregando até dar `time out`.

[image: time out]

A criação do token para troca de Password é gerado corretamente, acessando o link de troca ele funciona e edita corretamente. Porém o e-mail não está sendo enviado.

Config/environments/development.rb

```
  Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.
 
  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false
 
  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false
 
  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
 
  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
 
  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log
 
  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load
 
  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true
 
  # Adds additional error checking when serving assets at runtime.
  # Checks for improperly declared sprockets dependencies.
  # Raises helpful error messages.
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true
 
  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
 
  # Mail configuration
  
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:5000' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  # Apenas alterei os dados de domain, user_name e password por segurança
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :por => 587,
    :domain => 'mydomain.com.br',
    :user_name => 'email@domain.com.br',
    :password => 'mypassword',
    :authentication => 'plain',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
 
end
```

Para melhor visualização: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/ralfting/399f3386fa83af09fc96)

#### Log de erro

> Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 30414ms

[Development.log](https://gist.github.com/ralfting/4c6886ee5c906fbd5322)

Se alguém tiver passado por algo semelhante deixe sua resposta. Obrigado

#### Solução para `Forget Password`

Com a syntax que estava antes ele não estava configurando o smtp. Agora está assim

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 587,
    domain: 'localhost',
    user_name: 'my@gmail.com',
    password: 'myPass',
    authentication: 'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro está na conexão com o SMTP do gmail.

Vc está usando uma máquina com acesso a internet? Não tem firewall bloqueando?

Comment: Era isso sim o erro do `Forget Paassword` que não estava enviando o e-mail, porém ainda me resta o problema do `confirmable`.

Comment: O envio de email é igual para ambos, que erro dá?

Comment: Está dando o seguinte erro: `NoMethodError in Devise::Sessions#new`.
undefined method `new_confirmation_path' for #<#<Class:0xc422410>:0xbf71010>
[- Arquivo do Log](https://gist.github.com/ralfting/029d7d810f1a86a75927)

Comment: Aarquivo [User.rb](https://gist.github.com/ralfting/b017c43b955e0d2d83ae)

Comment: Tente reiniciar o server, se estiver usando rails 4.2, tente também um spring stop.